# Updating MySQL statement via jQuery Ajax not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have 3 tables:

- > category(id,name)
- > categoryattributes(id,attr_key,attr_display)
- > categoryhasattributes(category_id,attribute_id)

I want to update all the attributes for a given category using Ajax.

Here is Ajax code:

```
function editCategory() {
        var form = document.editForm;

        var dataString = $(form).serialize();


        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'editCategory.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);


            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$attrs = $_POST['attrs'];
$catid = $_POST['catid'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($attrs);$i++){
    if(mysqli_query($con, "
    update categoryhasattributes set attribute_id='$attrs[$i]'
    where category_id='$catid';
    ")){
        echo "success";
    }
}

?>
```

So the update statement is working but only the last element in the array `$attrs` is set.

For example, if `categoryid=10` and `$attrs = [1,2]`
when updating the table so the result is only:

> categoryhasattributes(10,2) //here first attribute must be 1
>   categoryhasattributes(10,2)

Looping through the array takes only the last element. Please help me fix the code!

Comment: Make sure $attrs really has two values. And make sure each values don't have extra characters with them like whitespaces.

Comment: if you notice when running the second update query so all the categories having id=10 will have attribute_id set to 2 so what i want is for each category assigning an attribute (10,1) - (10,2)

Comment: Are you sure it's UPDATE and not INSERT you need?

Comment: where category_id='$catid' will always UPDATE the same row as it updates with the same category_id always.

Comment: You may need to check if there is already a record with the same values as your $catid and $attr[] before doing a new INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your code and this was my result for the query strings:

```
update categoryhasattributes set attribute_id=1 where category_id=10
```

After your first query:

```
categoryhasattributes(10,1)
categoryhasattributes(10,1)

update categoryhasattributes set attribute_id=2 where category_id=10
```

After your second query:

```
categoryhasattributes(10,2)
categoryhasattributes(10,2)
```

The query is doing exactly what it is suppose to do.  First it updates category_id 10 and sets the attribute_id to 1.  Then it updates category_id 10 again and sets the attribute_id to 2.

Take a look at your tables and see if you can plan your query better.  You may need to add a third column in your categoryhashattributes table to make each row unique or for a particular id or something.

***UPDATE***

Add an id column to your

```
categoryhasattributes(id,category_id,attribute_id)
```

Pass the id to your query like this:

```
update categoryhasattributes set attribute_id='$attrs[$i]'
where category_id='$catid' && id='$id';
```

Comment: if you notice when running the second update query so all the categories having id=10 will have attribute_id set to 2 so what i want is for each category assigning an attribute (10,1) - (10,2)

Comment: The only way to do what you want is to assign an id to each attribute, then you can target each attribute separately in your query.  There is nothing unique about your data if you have multiple categoryid's with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the same record in your loop as $catid in your queries is always the same. It appears the loop only handles the last $attr[] value because it just overwrites the previous update.

```
"where category_id='$catid';" - problem
```

Rather than UPDATE query, I think you need INSERT one. Here's the updated code I made. Haven't tested it yet. But I hope it works fine already.

```
 <?php 

    require 'connection.php';

    $attrs = $_POST['attrs'];
    $catid = $_POST['catid'];

    for ($i=0;$i<count($attrs);$i++){
        if( cha_exists( $catid, $attrs[$i] ) == FALSE ) {
            $res = mysqli_query($con, "
            INSERT INTO categoryhasattributes (category_id, attribute_id ) VALUES('$catid', '$attrs[$i]');");

            if( $res ) {
                echo "success";
            }
        }
    }

    function cha_exists( $cat_id, $attr_id ) {
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "
        SELECT * FROM categoryhasattributes WHERE attribute_id='$attr_id'
        AND category_id='$cat_id';
        ");

        return mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0;
    }

    ?>
```